# How to get a pair with the highest value from a mapping?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I'm making a ballot contract, after a person votes, counter adds 1 to a spesified candidate

```
mapping(uint256 => mapping(uint256 => uint256)) public voteCountForCandidate;
```

Here is a mapping with two keys: ProposalID and CandidateID, how do I get a pair with the highest value from it?

Answer (score 0):

Solidity mapping does not support iteration. Generally, everything involving iteration should be avoided in Solidity smart contracts due to gas cost and block size limit issues.

The easiest way to get the highest value mapping is to store the highest value when a new entry is added.

```
highestValue = max(highestValue, newValue)
```